# Rails scan ActiveRecord for attribute change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am creating a matchmaking system in my rails application where users can post matches for a certain time. If the time the match is posted for is reached without being accepted I need to void that match by setting its active flag to false.

What would be the best approach for this? I have read bad things about cluttering up models with too many callbacks, and am not sure if ActiveModel Dirty is the best solution here. Does anybody have a suggestion that goes along with best practices and does not require a ton of DB queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ideas that should get you started. For all approaches I suggest encapsulating the business logic for creating a new match in a service object, to avoid the cluttering of the model you already mentioned.

- immediately after persisting, store the match' id in Redis using a pre-defined TTL. For example using a key in the form `matches:open:1234`. Whenever you need a list of open matches, just query the keys under `matches:open:*` and you can use those to do a targeted query on your ActiveRecord DB. Expiration will be completely out of your hair. You can also easily "touch" a record if you want to keep the match open for a bit longer. Just pay attention to your database transactions and the possibility of rollbacks: you don't want to write invalid database ids into Redis :)
- when creating the match, also enqueue a job (either via ActiveJob or a more specific framework like Sidekiq) that retrieves the record and checks whether it has been accepted in the meantime. You can optimize this by using something like `where(id: match_id, accepted_at: nil).first` and if `nil` is being returned, you can assume that the match has been accepted in the meantime without having to instantiate the record. If you need functionality to keep a match open for longer than the initial delay, you'll need to search for and cancel the already-enqueued job and enqueue a new one.

As for periodically querying all pending matches in a recurring job, it makes protection against race conditions a bit harder with regards to row level locks and also is much harder to scale, so I personally would advise against it.